# LibCURL login to website

Tags: c, cookies, authentication, libcurl

So I know there are other similar questions, which I've been reading as well, but my problem is unique I think. I'm trying to login to mojang.com (don't ask) and remain logged in for subsequent requests. But when I sent the POST request to the login page, it just dumps the login page back at me. How can I get PAST the login page?

I believe I've activated the cookie engine and the cookies are recorded and printed successfully but perhaps not being used?

My goal is to access this page after successful login: https://account.mojang.com/me

```
session* mojang_login(const char *user, const char *pass,
        const char *q1, const char *q2, const char *q3)
{
    const char *url = "https://account.mojang.com/login";
    const char *payload = construct_payload(user, pass);
    const char *ua =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0";
    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = {0};

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (!curl)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize curl\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, ua);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, payload);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    free((void*) payload);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        curl_err(res, errbuf);
        return NULL;
    }

    struct curl_slist *cookies;
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        curl_err(res, errbuf);
        return NULL;
    }

    while (cookies)
    {
        printf("\nCOOKIE DATA: %s\n", cookies->data);
        cookies = cookies->next;
    }

    session *s1 = NULL; /* safe_malloc(sizeof(session));*/

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(since you don't actually provide a full source code I can't tell you exactly but I'll instead speak of this problem in generic terms)

First, you need to make sure you record cookies from long enough before the login-POST. Some sites set the cookies when you view the login-page so you may need to fetch that first.

Then, you need to make sure you submit everything on the login as a browser would submit (including those hidden form fields you don't see in a browser view). A good way to figure that out is to use the browser's network tools to capture exactly what the browsers send and then you make sure your code sends the same things. You can then iterate a few times to make sure your requests are as similar as possible to the browsers'.

Of course you must enable cookies and you must follow redirects as most logins will take you to another page.